# What are the IB objects used in Mac OS X's Address Book?

Tags: cocoa, interface-builder, addressbook

Does anyone know what are the types of UI objects used in Mac Address book to edit the address components? I have started my first Cocoa application and in many instances I would like to have this look and feel as opposed to simple table views.

Answer (score 1):

It's all entirely custom view code involving `NSPopUpButton`s and `NSButton`s and `NSTextField`s. While you may not be able to get it for free in Interface Builder, it shouldn't be especially difficult to build from scratch.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'm still a newbie to Obj-C/Cocoa, it might be a challenge for me to build it from scratch!